# What is the reason for discrenpasies in extension icon sizes?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, icons

I added icons for all of the sizes below to the "icons" and "browser action icons" properties to see where Chrome would put them.

```
    "16": "icon16.png",
    "19": "icon19.png",
    "24": "icon24.png",
    "32": "icon32.png",
    "36": "icon36.png",
    "38": "icon38.png",
    "48": "icon48.png",
    "128": "icon128.png"
```

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/icons

According to the documentation for icons:  "You should always provide a 128x128 icon; it's used during installation and by the Chrome Web Store. Extensions should also provide a 48x48 icon, which is used in the extensions management page (chrome://extensions). You can also specify a 16x16 icon to be used as the favicon for an extension's pages."

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction

According to the documentation for browser icons:

```
"browser_action": {
          "default_icon": {                    // optional
            "16": "images/icon16.png",           // optional
            "24": "images/icon24.png",           // optional
            "32": "images/icon32.png"            // optional
          }
```

What I found is that the actual sizes on the screen are different from the dimensions of the image and the CSS size given to the image. For example, the 48x48 image used in chrome://extensions/ is displayed on the browser as 54x54 (checked size using MS Paint), but inspecting it with dev tools shows a 36x36 css value. So 48x48 = actual size, 54x54 size displayed in the browser, 36x36 CSS size given to it in the browser.

Something else I found is that, for example, the navicon icon uses the 32x32 image. Yet the space on screen is 24x24 (checked in MS Paint). Why not just use the 24x24 image I included?

Why these discrepansies?

And when I checked an official Google extension, the only icons it has are 128, 38, and 19. There's no 32x32 even though the docs say 32x32 should be included for Windows. This page does mention those sizes: https://chrome-apps-doc2.appspot.com/extensions/browserAction.html#icon, but it seems like an old page.

The docs say Chrome can rescale an icon to fit it to different sizes. So could I just give it a 128x128 one and be good? It displays well on my laptop but I don't know if other devices would have issues.

Comment: 128px is sufficient indeed, but some people like to manually draw/adjust 16px icon pixel-by-pixel for additional clarity. I do this.

Comment: Also re "Why these discrepansies?" that's because Chromium UI designers aren't technical people so they don't care about technicalities.